# Escape HTML entities and render URL dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, gatsby, sanity

The problem can be seen [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/iframe-dynamic-src)

I built a site using [Sanity](https://www.sanity.io/) headless CMS and GatsbyJS on the frontend.

I'm querying URLs dynamically so that it can be rendered inside the `src` attribute of an `</iframe>` The problem is when the user adds an URL containing `&amp`, pretty common for Google Calendar's embed code.

With `&amp` The link no longer works and the calendar breaks (goes blank). **Unless** I hardcode it directly in the `src` which is exactly what we want to avoid.

How can I mitigate/escape this issue and have it so I can render the URL accordingly?

I've looked into `encodeURI` , `encodeURIComponent`, even tried this custom function:

```js
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

No dice...

- Looking for a client-side JS solution or backend solution, if possible to do so, inside Sanity's ecosystem

My current implementation

```js
// sanity schema
export default {
  type: 'document',
  title: 'Google Calendar',
  name: 'calendar',
  fields: [
    {
      type: 'string',
      name: 'Title',
    },
    {
      type: 'url',
      name: 'URL',
      validation: (Rule) => Rule.required(),
    },
  ],
};

//gastby 
export default function GoogleCalendar() {
  const { calendar } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      calendar: allSanityCalendar {
        nodes {
          URL
          Title
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  if (!calendar.nodes.length) return null;
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {calendar.nodes.map((node) => (
          <iframe
            src={node.URL}
            id="test"
            title={node.Title}
            width="100%"
            height="1000px"
            async
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's a sandbox illustrating the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/iframe-dynamic-src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have your sandbox working: https://iframe-dynamic-src-pmxqbb.stackblitz.io

I've fixed it by:

```
  <iframe
    src={decodeURIComponent(
      encodeURIComponent(brokeUrl.replace(/&amp;/g, "&"))
    )}
    width="800"
    height="600"
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="no"
    content
  />
```

[Decoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) an [encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) URL that replaces globally the ampersands (`&amp;`) by `&`.

Comment: brillant! thank you so very much - any concerns w/ doing this on client-side as opposed to server-side?

Comment: Well, any computation effort that you can save to the client is performance earnt but it always depends on your setup, the use-cases (especially)/needs, and capabilities